# WPF C# Media Element Show first image of video

Tags: c#, wpf, button, audio, mediaelement

i have a .mov file that i want to play using MediaElement of WPF , i can play and pause with no worries as i use MediaState.Manual , but i want to show the first image or frame of the video when i load it , the source is set in code behind , i tried MediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled = true both code behind and xaml but it still doesn't show.

Here is my code ( xaml side ) :

```
   <DockPanel Height="386" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="731">
        <MediaElement Name="McMediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill" MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded" OpacityMask="#FF040410" Height="386" IsVisibleChanged="SingAlong_IsVisibleChanged" ScrubbingEnabled="True"></MediaElement>
    </DockPanel>
```

Code behind ( xaml.cs) :

```
    private void PlayAudio()
    {


        McMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        McMediaElement.Source = new Uri("../../SingAlong/GrassHopper and Ants/ants2.mov", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        McMediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled = true;

       McMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Play button
    {
        if (McMediaElement.Source != null)
        {
            McMediaElement.Play();
        }
        else
            PlayAudio();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Pause button
    {
        McMediaElement.Pause();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, you are loading your video (setting the `Source`) only when you click `button1`, yet you want the first frame to show before this happens. To accomplish this, you will have to load your video in another method, preferably when your `Page` or `Window` loads. Then you can do the following:

```
McMediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
McMediaElement.Play();
McMediaElement.Pause();
```

Comment: You can also drop the Play() and set the Position property to a timespan of 0 to achieve the same thing.